# How to detect device id from SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT

Tags: c++, service

I have the handler for SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT but I need to perform some action only if it's my specific device for any other device I need to do nothing 
how to I get the device Id from these parameters I get on deviceEnt?
`HandlerEx(DWORD dwControl, DWORD dwEventType, LPVOID lpEventData)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can cast the  lpEventData and get the name whihc contains the GUI

```
    PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR lpdb = (PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR)lpEventData
if( lpdb->dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE)
    {
        PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE pInterface = (PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE)lpdb;   
pInterface->dbcc_name  -> this contains the GUID
}
```